# how do I handle subview resizing in a UITableViewCell going in & out of EDIT MODE?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, layoutsubviews

QUESTION - How do I handle subview resizing in a UITableViewCell going in & out of EDIT MODE?

BACKGROUND - I've worked out how to size my UiLabels & UITableViewCell based around the text & font used.  I'm currently doign this in cellForRowAtIndexPath (I'm programmatically creating UILabels and adding as subviews to the existing contentView)

ASPECTS - So I'm hoping the answer would clear up things for me including:

1. Is the approach based around the fact one has to manually re-determine subview (e.g. UILabel) positioning (e.g. x/y/height/width) each time the UITableView goes into and out of edit mode?
2. If YES - which methods would one normally do this in?  e.g. cellForRowAtIndexPath?
3. If YES - in terms of catering for EDIT mode can one just assume a standard (non-changing) reduction amount (in pixcels) for the edit icons that would appear?
4. If NO - What is the approach here then?  use of scaling somehow? which attributes are requried to be set to allow this to happen automatically

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer to it [here](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/91172?tstart=0) in fact.